# Trigger a scheduled task "At task creation/modification" schtasks

Tags: scheduled-task, windows-command-prompt, schtasks

I am creating a schedules task to run just before it's created and deleted after it runs.

I am using the tool, schtasks to create the scheduled task, but i havent found the parameter to run the task "At task creation/modification"

```
schtasks /create /TN "Install Bpm" /SC ONCE /TR "C:\windows\system32\calc.exe -i silent" /Z
```

My question is; how can I create a scheduled task via command line, with the trigger “At task creation/modification".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is really only available using the `AT` command, as it is designed to perform single-action tasks.

You need to use the `/Create` to build the task from the command line.

Then you need to `/Run` the task by its `/TN` name.

Once the task is complete, the task can call the `/Delete` command against its own `/TN` name within the task to clean up after itself.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* create a scheduled task via command line, with the trigger "At task creation/modification". This is a security feature to prevent malwares from spawning new tasks in the background.

Not every options are available with `schtasks` and it is by design.

Comment: Actually, you can if you import a task via XML definition file using command line.

Answer (score 0):

One can accomplish this using the `MSFT_TaskRegistrationTrigger` class. Here's a minimal example of how to do so using PowerShell:

```
Register-ScheduledTask `
    -Action '<PLACEHOLDER>' `
    -TaskName '<PLACEHOLDER>' `
    -Trigger (Get-CimClass `
        -ClassName 'MSFT_TaskRegistrationTrigger' `
        -Namespace 'Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler');
```